# How to test drag & drop functionality in AngularJS e2e testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to test my application where I need to move a widget from one location to other, in other word I need to test drag & drop functionality in an end to end test.

How would I test this?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/123 and https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/fb46ec9bcd568510248831f11d43d0e2398cc606

Comment: @Nicolae Olariu the link (https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/fb46ec9bcd568510248831f11d43d0e2398cc606) you provided work for me

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue. The solution for me was to follow the advice in the Selenium issue here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604#c20

Starting with the example from @nilsK, here was my solution:

```
var yourOffset = {x:5,y:5};
ptor().actions()
    .mouseMove(yourElement,yourOffset)
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove(yourElement,{x:0,y:0}) // Initial move to trigger drag start
    .mouseMove(youTarget[,targetOffset]) // [] optional
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();
```

I think this also solves [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315571/drag-drop-with-protractor-by-repeater)

Answer (score 1):

you will need to chain your mouse actions:

```
var yourOffset = {x:5,y:5};
ptor().actions().
   mouseMove(yourElement,yourOffset).
   mouseDown().
   mouseMove(youTarget[,targetOffset]). // [] optional
   mouseUp().
   perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ptor.actions().dragAndDrop(el1, el2).perform();`

I have an [example](https://github.com/sergkr/swot/blob/master/test/e2e/editQuiz/quizEditor.js#L351) here from the test suite in my own application:

```
/**
 * Reorders questions by dragging and dropping.
 */
this.moveQuestion = function (questionToMove, positionToMoveTo) {
    return page.getQuestionField(positionToMoveTo).then(function (dest) {
        page.getDragHandle(questionToMove).then(function (dragHandle) {
            ptor.actions().dragAndDrop(dragHandle, dest).perform();
            ptor.sleep(800);    // wait for animation
        });
    });
};
```