# Drag & Drop with Protractor by Repeater

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, repeater, protractor

There are a few questions similar to this one & and I have read them all.  However I still can't get the Action Sequence to work as expected in protractor.

I have a list of  items that are draggable and I need to test results after they are re-arranged.  However I can't get the dragging/dropping to work correctly.  Here is a simplified mock up of what I have so far.

helper functions:

```
var getRow = function (num){
      return element(by.repeater('p in pList').row(num - 1));
};

var getField = function (rowNum){
    return getRow(rowNum).findElement(by.css('td.ng-binding'));
};

var moveIndexToIndex = function (startIndex, endIndex) { 
  return getField(endIndex).then(function (endPoint) {
      getField(startIndex).then(function (startPoint) { 
          // browser.actions().dragAndDrop(startPoint, endPoint).perform(); // doesn't work either
          browser.actions().
            mouseMove(startPoint, {x: 0, y: 0}).
            mouseDown().
            mouseMove(endPoint).
            mouseUp().
            perform();   
      });
    });
});
```

I am calling the move helper function with literals like so:

```
moveIndexToIndex(2, 5);
```

And the html look something like this:

```
<tbody>
          <!-- ngRepeat: p in pList -->
          <tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 1</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 2</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 3</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 4</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 5</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 6</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 7</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 8</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 9</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList --><tr ng-repeat="p in pList" eg-draggable="p" eg-droppable="eg-droppable" class="ng-scope" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;">
            <td class="ng-binding">DummyValue 10</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: p in pList -->
</tbody>
```

How can I get dragging and dropping to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: It has no error message just passes the dummy expect statement that I have in there.  I can see that it tries to click on the starting point element, but there is no dragging happening.

Comment: @willko747 I was trying to perform drag and drop, i can drag an item but it is not drop at the location specified. Could you please suggest something for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed this with the updated changes to protractor.  I was missing the .getWebElement() part which replaced the .find() method.

```
browser.actions().
        mouseMove(startPoint.getWebElement(), {x: 0, y: 0}).
        mouseDown().
        mouseMove(endPoint.getWebElement()).
        mouseUp().
        perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.dragAndDrop` method

```
var moveIndexToIndex = function (startIndex, endIndex) { 
  return getField(endIndex).then(function (endPoint) {
      getField(startIndex).then(function (startPoint) { 
          // browser.actions().dragAndDrop(startPoint, endPoint).perform(); // doesn't work either
          browser.actions().
            dragAndDrop(startPoint, {x: (startIndex - endIndex) * 400, y: 0}).
            perform(); 
      });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how you're going to calculate `x` and `y`. But this is how you usually do it.

As a side note, use `$` instead of `findElement`. It's being deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, still getting same results with the above dragAndDrop suggestion.  It seems like it tries to click, but still no dragging is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. The solution for me was to follow the advice in the Selenium issue here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604#c20

Starting with the example from @willko747, here was my solution:

```
browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(startPoint.getWebElement(), {x: 0, y: 0})
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove(startPoint.getWebElement(), {x: 5, y: 5}) // Initial move to trigger drag start
    .mouseMove(endPoint.getWebElement())
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();
```

I think this also solves [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984267/how-to-test-drag-drop-functionality-in-angularjs-e2e-testing)

Answer (score 0):

```
elementToDrag.click();
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elementToDrag, locationToDragTo))).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions mentioned above worked for me.
I could see the element (to be dragged) getting selected and the mouse cursor changing to a 4-way scroll arrow. However, the drag was not happening.
What worked for me is the solution I found in GitHub: https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175
Download the file: "native_js_drag_and_drop_helper.js"

I am sharing the code for "native_js_drag_and_drop_helper.js".

```
module.exports =function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
    var EVENT_TYPES = {
        DRAG_END: 'dragend',
        DRAG_START: 'dragstart',
        DROP: 'drop'
    }

    function createCustomEvent(type) {
        var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent")
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            setData: function(type, val) {
                this.data[type] = val
            },
            getData: function(type) {
                return this.data[type]
            }
        }
        return event
    }

    function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
        if (node.dispatchEvent) {
            return node.dispatchEvent(event)
        }
        if (node.fireEvent) {
            return node.fireEvent("on" + type, event)
        }
    }

    var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START)
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event)

    var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP)
    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent)

    var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END)
    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent)
}
```

Implementation of this Drag-and-Drop function:

```
var dragAndDropFn = require("./../../../TestScripts/CommonFunctions/native_js_drag_and_drop_helper.js");
var inputX = element(by.xpath("XPATH OF ELEMENT TO BE MOVED"));
var targetX = element(by.xpath("XPATH OF THE TARGET LOCATION"));
browser.executeScript(dragAndDropFn, inputX.getWebElement(), targetX.getWebElement());
```