# Protractor dragAndDrop by offset Location of Element

Tags: drag-and-drop, location, action, protractor

**Question:**
Is there a way that I can offset the starting location to drag?

I would like to edit the location of where to start the dragging process.  Testing on another element that I can grab without adjustment the below code works fine:

```
var controlPoint = $$('circle.points').first();
browser.actions().
        dragAndDrop(controlPoint.getLocation(), {x: 500, y: 50}).
        perform();
```

However when I try to set it up for modifying the location like this:

```
var controlPoint = $$('circle.points').first();
controlPoint.getLocation().then(function (loc) { 
    // would modify loc.x and loc.y here if this didn't give an error
    browser.actions().
        dragAndDrop(loc, {x: 500, y: 50}).
        perform();
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Single Segments should test dragging and dropping of control points
   Message:
     UnknownError: unknown error: at least an element or offset should be set
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.125)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64)
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: unknown error: at least an element or offset should be set
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.125)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64)
==== async task ====
mouseMove
    at Array.forEach (native)
==== async task ====
ActionSequence.perform
    at /Users/willko/Desktop/e2e_sketching/specs/sketch2.js:25:6
==== async task ====
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `dragAndDrop(loc` because `dragAndDrop()` takes an ElementFinder or WebElement as first argument and you're passing `loc` which is an Object with `x` and `y` properties.

Try this:

```
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(controlPoint, {x: 500, y: 50}).
    perform();
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but I will mark as accepted since it points out the cause of the error.  The way you can edit start location is through the mouseMove() method though, shown in one of my other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315571/drag-drop-with-protractor-by-repeater).  It is a more manual process though. Brady's comment on that page is very helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to parameterize the second parameter or offset to dragAndDrop? Drag and drop works with hardcoded offset object like here described {x: 500, y: 50} but treats {x:x, y:y}, at least for me, as undefined (in ActionSequence.mouseMove function).

Comment: I think I ran into a similar problem doing the same.  You might try rounding the parameters that get passed in.  This function should work as long as it gets integers though. `var dragWithOffset = function(startElement, x_offset, y_offset) {
    return browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(startElement.getWebElement(), {
      x: x_offset,
      y: y_offset
    }).
    perform();
  }; `