# How to drag and drop a slider in protractor?

Tags: slider, protractor

[image]

HTML code :

```
<div class="ngrs-range-slider ng-isolate-scope" range-slider="" min="0" max="30" attach-handle-values=
"true" model-min="experience.minVal" model-max="experience.maxVal" style="margin: 28px 0px 0px 0px;">

`<div class="ngrs-runner"><div class`="ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-min" style="left: 0%;"><i></i></div>

<div class="ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-max" style="left: 10%;"><i></i></div>
```

```
<div class="ngrs-value-runner ngrs-attached-handles"><div class="ngrs-value ngrs-value-min ng-hide" ng-show="showValues" style="left: 3.33333%;"><div class="ng-binding">1</div></div>

<div class="ngrs-value ngrs-value-max ng-hide" ng-show="showValues" style="left: 10%; right: auto;"><div class="ng-binding">3</div></div></div></div>
```

How to drag a slider, I tried with css selectors but it is not working.

In my problem, am only getting X position locator value not Y position locator value and I have only two class values i.e : `ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-min` and `'ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-max'` Using these two values how to drag slider.

Comment: See the [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315571/drag-drop-with-protractor-by-repeater?rq=1) and/or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor?rq=1)

Comment: @Gunderson I tried both answer and still am not able to drag slider. Can you please help me out of this.   I am getting this error :  Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .ngrs-handle.ngrs-handle-max.ngrs-over.ngrs-down). Why am getting this error is because of locator only visible after moving the slider to target position so it is showing error. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an answer

```
this.test_slider = function(){
        var sliderBar = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css(".ngrs-handle.ngrs-handle-max"));
        browser.actions().dragAndDrop(sliderBar,{x:50,y:0}).perform(); 
        ptor.sleep(10000);
        expect(sliderBar.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('7');

    };
```