# Drag and drop using protractor in dthmlx component

Tags: angularjs, protractor, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using dhtmlx scheduler component with angular. [Dhtmlx scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/)  You can find drag and drop of events in live demo of **Timeline view**.

I need to writer protractor test case for it. How can I perform drag and drop of dhtmlx component using protractor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demos available on the Dhtmlx scheduler page don't use angular. I've found [another suitable demo page](http://dhtmlx.github.io/angular-gantt-demo/) which I would use as an example.

The general idea is pretty simple - use `dragAndDrop()` function. Unfortunately it is not documented on the [API documentation page](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api). May be this is because it is coming from webdriverjs and protractor has nothing to do with it. Anyway, currently, you can find some information and samples here:

- [How to do drag and drop in protractor?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/123)
- [actions_spec.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/spec/basic/actions_spec.js)
- [How to test drag & drop functionality in AngularJS e2e testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984267/how-to-test-drag-drop-functionality-in-angularjs-e2e-testing)

Basically you can either move an element by `x` or `y` offset to the left or right or top or bottom; or, you can move to an another element.

Here's an example (moving `Task #1` by 1000 to the right):

```
describe("Sample test", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get("http://dhtmlx.github.io/angular-gantt-demo/");
        browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    it("should move the task", function () {
        var task = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="gantt_bars_area"]//div[@task_id="2"]'));

        browser.actions().dragAndDrop(
            task,
            {x:1000, y:0}
        ).perform();

        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can manually chain `mouseDown()`, `mouseMove()`, `mouseUp()` actions, examples:

- [How to simulate a drag and drop action in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor)
- [Drag & Drop with Protractor by Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315571/drag-drop-with-protractor-by-repeater)